# PowerShell Round & Format Float to max 2 decimals?

Tags: powershell, floating-point, format

I found lots of stuff to format floats to common known numbers,
but how can I format a float to a max of 2 decimals, but only if the decimals are needed?

Examples:

```
  1.11 # not 1.111
  1.12 # it was 1.116 (round up)
  1.1  # not 1.10
  1    # not 1.00
```

if I do

```
  $('{0:N2}' -f $flt)
```

I get

```
  1.00 # :(
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use `[math]::round`, ie:

```powershell
[math]::round(1.111,2)
```

will return `1.11` and

```powershell
[math]::round(1.00,2)
```

yields `1`

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `#` character in a [custom numeric format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) to include non-zero digits in a value.

```
> 1.001,1.101,1.111 | % { '{0:0.##}' -f $_ }
1
1.1
1.11
```

The `N2` [standard numeric format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString) is basically equivalent to `0.00`, which produces a fixed number of decimal digits.