# How do round memory size

Tags: powershell

I have this script line:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object  TotalPhysicalMemory, @{Name="GB";Expression={$_.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB}}
```

How to round this result 2 separate places after coma.
result at the moment is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEgJ8.jpg)

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell [Core] (version 6 and above), where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell Round & Format Float to max 2 decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037021/powershell-round-format-float-to-max-2-decimals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the format string operator and specify the number of decimal places like this

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem |
  Select-Object TotalPhysicalMemory, 
                @{Name="GB";Expression={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB)}}
```